# How can I optimize this nginx proxy cache configuration?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I want to cache all `*.html` files in a Nginx reverse proxy, So I added the config:

```
# Original configuration
location = / {
    proxy_pass   http://192.168.12.12:91;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

# Added for cache
location ~ \.html {
    proxy_pass   http://192.168.12.12:91;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_cache cache_one;
    proxy_cache_key $host$uri$is_args$args;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302 1m;
    proxy_cache_valid any 1m;
    expires     1m;
}
```

Repeat twice `proxy_pass` and `proxy_set_header` feel bad

How can I optimize this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A nested location is the right way to create locations with regular expressions and it should do the trick for what you want to achieve.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass          http://192.168.12.12:91;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    location ~* \.html$ {
        proxy_cache          cache_one;
        proxy_cache_key      $host$uri$is_args$args;
        proxy_cache_valid    any 1m;
        expires              1m;
    }
}
```

I’m not totally sure if the nested location is really using the options from the outer location block. If it doesn’t (I can’t test this right now) you could create separate files.

```
location / {
    include proxy.conf;

    location ~* \.html$ {
        include              proxy.conf;
        proxy_cache          cache_one;
        proxy_cache_key      $host$uri$is_args$args;
        proxy_cache_valid    any 1m;
        expires              1m;
    }
}
```

### `proxy.conf`

```
    proxy_pass          http://192.168.12.12:91;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

This is definitely going to work.